# Numpy Array Element-Comparison to Float64

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, comparison

I am trying to return an array (element-wise) of True/False values on a numpy array comparsion to a float64 static variable. Input and desired output array is 1x10 (column x row)

```
array = np.random.randint(10, size=(10,1))
```

Attempt 1:

```
bool = np.any((array >= min)&(array <= max))
```

Attempt 2:

```
bool = np.logical_and((array >= min),(array <= max))
```

Attempt 3:

```
bool = np.any([(array >= min)&(array <= max)])
```

Attempt 4:

```
bool = np.array(np.any([(array >= min)&(array <= max)]))
```

All four of the above methods produce this output in the interpreter

```
print(bool) = True
```

When desired output looks something like:

```
print(bool) = [True
               False
               True
               True
               False
               False
               True
               False
               False
               True]
```

Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide me!

Comment: print your original `array`, notice that every individual value is wrapped in an array, is this intentional?

Comment: No it was not, I am as you call "noob" haha especially with numpy

Comment: OK so you actually just want size to be `(10)` and not `(10,1)` :), and then there's no need for `.ravel()` in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`.ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to get your output in the desired shape.

try this:

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 1))

min = 2.2
max = 6.6
result = ((array >= min) & (array <= max)).ravel()

print(result)
```

Output (example, as it is random):

> [False  True  True  True  True  True False False False  True]

Comment: just confirmed in compiler that .ravel option works! Neat find, didn't know this option existed. Very useful